# Do special buildings need citizens to produce benefits?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

In Civ 5, do special buildings (ones that can generate Great People) need citizens to produce their benefits other than Great Person Points?

**For example:**

The [Bank building gives +25% Gold](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_buildings_in_Civ5) and 1 Merchant Specialist Slot. If you do not put a citizen in the Merchant Specialist Slot, do you still get the 25% Gold bonus?

Note: 
Running Gods & Kings Expansion.

Answer (score 11):

The building will still have its normal effect without assigning people to it. In this case, a bank with no merchant will still add +25% gold.

Specialist slots just give you the option of creating a specialist in that building. They won't directly affect how effective the building is but they do produce resources and, more importantly, great person points.